# pragmatically login to outlook in office 365 and more

Tags: authentication, outlook, office365, mailto

Basically I want to simulate "mailto" behaviors in a browser. Here is what we need to do step by step:

1) click a link called "Email" in a web page.

2) automatically log the user in to the outlook.office.com.

3) open "create new email" interface.

4) have saved email addresses showed in "To" field; saved subject showed in "subject" field automatically.

Is it possible doing this in outlook in office 365?

Thanks,

Alex

Answer (score 0):

Much of what you want to do requires an actual application to be built, as you can't just automatically authenticate against a user's Office 365 Mailbox and run custom code from just a link in a web page.

If you built a web app you can use the [Discovery Service REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/discovery-service-rest-operations) to authenticate your app and then use the Office 365 REST APIs to create draft emails, but you can't then display this email in the Outlook Web Application.

Similarly, you can build a Mail Addin and use Exchange Web Services to create a draft email from a button in your addin's web UI, and then you can use [Mailbox.displayMessageForm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/fp142249.aspx) to display this email (which you can't do via the REST APIs).

Comment: Thank you, Eric. I looked up REST API before I post here and also found out it's not my answer. We were able to achieve this with another email system: Zimbra, since it provides some sort of web API. just don't know if outlook in office 365 are providing similar web APIs for me to achieve what I described here.

Comment: Well, Office 365 does have several web APIs - which I've referenced. Take another look at Mail Addins.